# JSON - * equivalent to return all values within timeStamp

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using `Gson` with Java and I'm looking to return all the JSON objects that have a `timeStamp` value within a given range.

An example JSON object:

```
{  
   "blobJson":"x",
   "deviceMfg":10,
   "eventCode":0,
   "sensorClass":3,
   "sensorUUID":"19455746",
   "timeStamp":1.482877651569025E9,
   "uID":"19455746_3_10"
}
```

I'm able to access the attributes individually but I'm not sure how to return the entire object and then continue onto the next object.

At the moment I'm accessing each object via the URL using `HttpURLConnection`:

```
http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:yyy/SensorCentral/REST/SensorData/
```

With the sensor ID appended onto the end so the final URL is something like:

```
http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:yyy/SensorCentral/REST/SensorData/000001_3_10
```

EDIT:

I want to be able to search past events from the specified `sensorUUID` - at the moment when I access the URL provided it gives me the latest event for that ID. How do I go about returning the past events for that `sensorUUID`.

Comment: Do you want to return jsonobject which contains timestamp from webservice? Update with more details and specific please

Comment: I've added some additional details on what I am looking.

Comment: Looks like it's more a question of how to use this SensorCentral API to return the objects you're looking for.

Comment: If @Aaron is right then why don't you filter jsonobject using param value and return filter obj?

Comment: @atiqkhaled What I understand is that he correctly receives the kind of object he's posted when he calls `http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:yyy/SensorCentral/REST/SensorData/19455746_3_10`, but would like other data about older measures/events/whatever. The only way to answer this is by looking the documentation of his service's API, which we don't have access to.

Comment: To speculate a little more, it seems like the URL currently used only returns the latest item, and he should find a way (maybe query parameters to this same URL? maybe another URL?) to either list all data (then filter the result), list data between two timestamps, or list the data which precedes a specific data (and iteratively work backward until all the desired data is retrieved)